# How to get a datetime in a format from hive query?

Tags: sql, string, datetime, hive

```
hql="
  select DISTINCT b.mid, from_unixtime(b.create_time,'yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss'), to_id from
      (select mid, create_time, to_id, dt from mark_table where dt>=$dt1 and dt<=$dt2 and to_id = 'Category_001' ) b
   
  "
```

I have a hive query above, and the 'b.create_time' is a column with date, but the default time format of this column is like this:

```
1594553700
```

I think it is time in seconds? I hope to convert it using this:

```
from_unixtime(b.create_time,'yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss')
```

But it gives an error, saying that b.create_time can't be a string for that function to work.

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1594553700` does look like a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970): it corresponds to Sunday, July 12, 2020 11:35:00 AM.

`from_unixtime()` is the right function to turn it to a formatted date string. But it seems like you are storing this timestamp as a string (which is definitely not a good idea), while [the function wants a number as argument](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions).

Just explicitly cast to the correct datatype:

```
from_unixtime(cast(b.create_time as bigint),'yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss')
```

Comment: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh.mm.ss' doesn't return 24 hours format. How to specify in 24-hour format?

Comment: @marlon: your question did not mention that. I guess you can just use `HH` instead of `hh`... Is this the reason why you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: Your answer is great, and I just want to know how to get 24-hour format. I am testing HH.mm.ss format. I will accept it.

Comment: It seems working. Should I also use HH.MM.SS, or just HH.mm.ss?